# Reinitialize global variables without refreshing the page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, global-variables

Mine is a web Application, In a jsp page I have a div(outerDiv), inside which many inner Divs are added by dragging and dropping contents and a set of global variables are initialised !

I have the following requirement.
  I have a button click, as like refreshing the whole page I need to clear and reset all the contents of the outerDiv, i.e., clear the inner Div and reinitialize all the global variables present in js file without refreshing the page.

I found jquery ***.empty***  the outerDiv, By calling `$("#attrList1").empty();`

But If I again drag and drop any content inside outerDiv, it cannot be added as the div is removed.

How do I do this ? How to reset the global variables in a javascript file?

Any suggestions !

Comment: can you provide a fiddle as we can give answer to reset the global variables but i think it will not solve your problem you need that DIV reseting problem solution too.

Comment: the global variable can be reset by re-adding the relevant script tag to the document. the problem is likely not globals though, it's pre-bound events, which need to be manually un-bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a global variable :

```
 var currentURL = document.URL;
```

Then to refresh the inner div i.e., to refresh a particular div content, try this:

```
 $('#outerDivContentID').load(currentURL+ ' #outerDivContentID');
 /*Note, be sure to include a space before the hastag.*/
```

At this point of time, i.e., when u click the button, reinitialize the global variables by setting a flag.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reset your global variables. Have them in a function and call it when you need to reset.

```
$(function(){
//declare global variables or initialize them like var i=0;
 var init = function(){
// set the variables to their inital values i.e i = 0;
};

// Do whatever you want.
// Call the init to reset.
init();
});
```